# How can I hyperlink a webpage and an email mailto link in a standard Windows Phone page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, hyperlink, mailto

So I want to add a web hyperlink in an WP page and also an email option.

so when the user interacts/ presses the link it navigates in a separate window using bing web browser/ default

and with an email link, it opens up the default e-mail setup installed on the device?

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the mailto functionality is possible - the way I did it was to handle the mouse event and use the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.EmailComposeTask to create the email and open the mail client).  See [How to: Use the Email Compose Task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394003%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do the same thing with the WebBrowserTask:
[How to: Use the Web Browser Task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394020%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Then after you have the codebehind or viewmodel stuff working, you'll just need to style your text to look like a link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about mailto?
Checkout w3school's demo on it and let me know! 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

Comment: for windows phone i mean not for a website!